# Replicate Dockers network mode `container:<name>` with a user created network

Tags: docker, docker-network

So lets say I have 2 containers that needs to share the same network.
I can do this

```
docker run some_image
```

and then do

```
docker run --network=container:some_image another_image
```

`another_image` would now join the same IPC namespace as `some_image`.

But could one replicate this by a pre-defined network?

Say like:

```
docker network create my_network
```

then

```
docker run --network=my_network some_image
```

```
docker run --network:my_network another_image
```

Are these the same thing? Or is it possible to replicate the first option but first create a common network?

Comment: It's pretty unusual IME to use `--network=container:...`; this means "be the same device" as distinct from "use the same network".  What leads you to need this setup?

Comment: There is actually no need. That is how the setup looks today. Its more that I am a noob when it comes to docker networks. And dont really know the difference. But if that is an anti pattern then it perhaps make sense to try out something else.

Answer (score 0):

They are both valid approaches and they work. Using `--network container:name` makes your intentions clear: you want to be on the same network as the other container. And this helps the readers of your code.

Of course you can maybe achieve the same by calling the network `common_network_container1_container2` but I find it uglier. It's a matter of style in the end.

Comment: Setting aside cleanness. How can I achieve the same network setup with `common_network_container1_container2` as `--network container:name` would be set up. I guess what I am asking its possible to configure a user created network to hold the same properties as `--network container:name` would create? Or are these the same by default?

Answer (score 0):

> Are these the same thing?

No. The first case spawns one network for all containers spawned from the image on `docker run some_image` to connect to. When using `--network container:<container_name>`, containers *use* that container's network stack as their own (I.E: they share the same "hardware" and network config, you can verify that by running `hostname` inside both containers). The documentation offers a [good example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-container) of the effect this produces. Notice how both processes communicate through each other through the localhost interface.

On the other hand, when using user-defined networks, containers can *connect* to it and communicate with other container's through their names (hostname) or IPs. That is, there is no shared network stack and each container is an isolated host in the network.

> But could one replicate this by a pre-defined network?

Yes, you could issue the following commands so that your containers all share the network stack:

```bash
docker network create foobar
docker run --network=foobar --name container1 some_image
docker run --network=container:container1 another_image
```

Inside both containers, running `hostname` would yield the same value.

Comment: Hm, I think I might have worded it a bit confusing. I want to create (given that its not already the same) a user defined network, that behaves exactly the same as if I were to start a container and connect antoher one to it using the `--network=container:name` option

Comment: Ah I think I understand now. You want to have a user-defined, shareable, network stack such that all containers using it could, for example, share hostname, ip, etc, within that network, right?

Comment: Yes, correct!!!

Comment: Curious, what's the use case? IOMK

Comment: Perhaps that I something that I aslo should have stated more verbose, my idea is that I dont want the second container to be dependent on that the first one is already up. Since I want to do this async.

Comment: Beats me. Only thing I can think of is to have a dummy container to use as target and make sure it's running (as you would make sure the network's created)